# Escape character within single quotes

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm having an issue figuring out how to ignore signs and variables in a single quote string statement.
I am attempting to update a table with the new text with structure such as:

```
update xxx
set xxx =
'Our Ref. $BOOKING_NO$
.......
Kind regards'
```

Comment: What's wrong with code you posted? It will put that single-quotes-enclosed-string into the XXX column. What would you want to do (if that's not "it")?

Comment: Your code works without errors [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mbD9pWuo)

Answer (score 1):

If your $ chars are being interpreted, it isn't by Oracle ($ isn't special in Oracle anyway, and between single-quotes everything is a string), but rather by your client program or maybe shell script. If, for example, you are running this in SQL*Plus from a Unix-based shell script, you will need to use the appropriate means required by the shell you use to prevent the shell from interpreting $ and ' characters.